# Genymotion Lollipop preview image does not boot

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, genymotion

I have the Lollipop Preview - Nexus 5 device. However, the Genymotion device doesn't boot. When I take a look at the logs, it gets stuck at `E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying`. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
--------- beginning of main
E/vinput-seamless(    0): found seamless mouse device
--------- beginning of system
D/local_opengl(    0): Starting local_opengl
I/lowmemorykiller(    0): Using in-kernel low memory killer interface
I/mediaserver(   73): ServiceManager: 0xb6116d40
I/AudioFlinger(   73): Using default 3000 mSec as standby time.
I/ServiceManager(   73): Waiting for service batterystats...
I/SurfaceFlinger(  171): SurfaceFlinger is starting
I/SurfaceFlinger(  171): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
I/Vold    (  170): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
D/libEGL  (  171): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
D/        (  171): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb6f1a1c0, tid 171
D/libEGL  (  171): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
D/libEGL  (  171): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
D/Genyd   (   67): Received Get Capabilities
D/        (   67): Socket deconnection
D/Genyd   (   67): Received Get GenymotionVersion
D/Genymotion(   67): Received Get GenymotionVersion
D/Genyd   (   67): Received Set Clipboard
D/Genymotion(   67): Received Set Clipboard
D/Genyd   (   67): Received Set Clipboard
D/Genymotion(   67): Received Set Clipboard
D/Genyd   (   67): Received Set TokenValidity
D/Genymotion(   67): Received Set TokenValidity 1
E/setdpi  (  194): Setting DPI to 480
E/SurfaceFlinger(  171): hwcomposer module not found
W/SurfaceFlinger(  171): no suitable EGLConfig found, trying a simpler query
I/SurfaceFlinger(  171): EGL information:
I/SurfaceFlinger(  171): vendor    : Android
I/SurfaceFlinger(  171): version   : 1.4 Android META-EGL
I/SurfaceFlinger(  171): extensions: EGL_KHR_get_all_proc_addresses EGL_ANDROID_presentation_time EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_fence_sync EGL_ANDROID_image_native_buffer
I/SurfaceFlinger(  171): Client API: OpenGL_ES
I/SurfaceFlinger(  171): EGLSurface: 8-8-8-8, config=0x1
I/SurfaceFlinger(  171): OpenGL ES informations:
I/SurfaceFlinger(  171): vendor    : Google (Intel)
I/SurfaceFlinger(  171): renderer  : Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000)
I/SurfaceFlinger(  171): version   : OpenGL ES 2.0 (4.0.0 - Build 9.17.10.2817)
I/SurfaceFlinger(  171): extensions: GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float
I/SurfaceFlinger(  171): GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 8192
I/SurfaceFlinger(  171): GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 8192
D/SurfaceFlinger(  171): setOrientation, mFbdev=0xb6f930c0, mFbDev->setOrientation=0xb6af1d40, orientation=0
I/gralloc_vbox86(  171): setOrientation: orientation=0
D/SurfaceFlinger(  171): Set power mode=2, type=0 flinger=0xb6f5e000
I/ServiceManager(   73): Waiting for service batterystats...
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
I/ServiceManager(   73): Waiting for service batterystats...
D/SurfaceFlinger(  171): shader cache generated - 24 shaders in 1645.280151 ms
D/libEGL  (  206): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
D/        (  206): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb661a6f0, tid 220
D/libEGL  (  206): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
D/libEGL  (  206): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
D/        (  171): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb6f1a680, tid 184
I/ServiceManager(   73): Waiting for service batterystats...
I/ServiceManager(   73): Waiting for service batterystats...
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
I/CameraService(   73): CameraService started (pid=73)
V/EmulatedCamera_GenyCamera(   73): Initialize:
V/EmulatedCamera_GenyCamera(   73):    initializing back camera on local srv port 24801
V/EmulatedCamera_GenyDevice(   73): Initialize: Connected to the emulated camera service 'back'
V/EmulatedCamera_Device(   73): initializeWhiteBalanceModes with auto, 1.000000, 1.000000
V/EmulatedCamera_Device(   73): initializeWhiteBalanceModes with incandescent, 1.380000, 0.600000
V/EmulatedCamera_Device(   73): initializeWhiteBalanceModes with daylight, 1.090000, 0.920000
V/EmulatedCamera_Device(   73): initializeWhiteBalanceModes with twilight, 0.920000, 1.220000
V/EmulatedCamera_Device(   73): setWhiteBalanceMode with white balance auto
V/EmulatedCamera_GenyCamera(   73): getCameraOrientation: camera orientation set to 90
V/EmulatedCamera_GenyCamera(   73): Initialize: Geny camera back is initialized. Current frame is 640x480
V/EmulatedCamera_GenyCamera(   73): Initialize:
V/EmulatedCamera_GenyCamera(   73):    initializing front camera on local srv port 24811
V/EmulatedCamera_GenyDevice(   73): Initialize: Connected to the emulated camera service 'front'
V/EmulatedCamera_Device(   73): initializeWhiteBalanceModes with auto, 1.000000, 1.000000
V/EmulatedCamera_Device(   73): initializeWhiteBalanceModes with incandescent, 1.380000, 0.600000
V/EmulatedCamera_Device(   73): initializeWhiteBalanceModes with daylight, 1.090000, 0.920000
V/EmulatedCamera_Device(   73): initializeWhiteBalanceModes with twilight, 0.920000, 1.220000
V/EmulatedCamera_Device(   73): setWhiteBalanceMode with white balance auto
V/EmulatedCamera_GenyCamera(   73): getCameraOrientation: camera orientation set to 90
V/EmulatedCamera_GenyCamera(   73): Initialize: Geny camera front is initialized. Current frame is 640x480
I/CameraService(   73): Loaded "Emulated Camera Module" camera module
I/AudioPolicyService(   73): AudioPolicyService CSTOR in new mode
I/AudioPolicyManager(   73): loadAudioPolicyConfig() loaded /system/etc/audio_policy.conf
I/AudioFlinger(   73): loadHwModule() Loaded primary audio interface from Genymotion audio HW HAL (audio) handle 1
I/genymotion_audio(   73): Starting pcm server
I/genymotion_audio(   73): out sampling rate 44100
I/AudioFlinger(   73): HAL output buffer size 880 frames, normal sink buffer size 1056 frames
I/AudioMixer(   73): found effect "Multichannel Downmix To Stereo" from The Android Open Source Project
E/MonoPipe(   73): Failed to fetch local time frequency when constructing a MonoPipe (res = -32).  getNextWriteTimestamp calls will be non-functional
E/local_camera(  177): We have a problem with the player connection 111 (Connection refused)
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
I/iptables(   69): iptables v1.4.20: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
I/iptables(   69): Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
I/iptables(   69): iptables terminated by exit(3)
E/Netd    (   69): exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t nat -N oem_nat_pre
I/iptables(   69): iptables v1.4.20: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
I/iptables(   69): Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
I/iptables(   69): iptables terminated by exit(3)
E/Netd    (   69): exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j oem_nat_pre
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
I/iptables(   69): iptables v1.4.20: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
I/iptables(   69): Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
I/iptables(   69): iptables terminated by exit(3)
E/Netd    (   69): exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t nat -N natctrl_nat_POSTROUTING
I/iptables(   69): iptables v1.4.20: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
I/iptables(   69): Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
I/iptables(   69): iptables terminated by exit(3)
E/Netd    (   69): exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j natctrl_nat_POSTROUTING
V/NatController(   69): runCmd(/system/bin/iptables -F natctrl_FORWARD) res=0
V/NatController(   69): runCmd(/system/bin/iptables -A natctrl_FORWARD -j DROP) res=0
V/NatController(   69): runCmd(/system/bin/iptables -t nat -F natctrl_nat_POSTROUTING) res=3
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
D/MDnsDS  (   69): MDnsSdListener::Hander starting up
D/MDnsDS  (   69): MDnsSdListener starting to monitor
D/MDnsDS  (   69): Going to poll with pollCount 1
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
I/dex2oat (  119): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 40228(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 14% free, 23MB/27MB, paused 222us total 245.319ms
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
I/dex2oat (  119): Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 21296 in void org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.HTMLSchema.<init>()
W/dex2oat (  119): Compilation of boolean android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) took 103.947ms
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (   78): missing packages.list; retrying
```

Comment: Still the same problem with the official Android 5 devices released today. Have you tried contacting Genymotion support?

Comment: @Jose_GD, confirmed. I just contacted support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that my VT-x was disabled. I was asked to enable it via BIOS and when I did, it worked like a charm. In addition to enabling VT-x, updating the video card drivers helps.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue.  It took over half an hour to get to that point.  But then it started repeating the following message:

12-08 22:29:11.955 E/sdcard  (   76): missing packages.list; retrying

I stopped it after about 20 minutes of this message.  (Cannot post a comment so I entered it as an answer even though I have no answer.).

Comment: I have the same error with all 5 and 5.1 Genymotion devices:   

$--------- beginning of crash 78-78/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xbd20 in tid 78 (main)   
80-80/? E/sdcard﹕ missing packages.list; retrying $  
  
despite AMD virtualization in BIOS is enabled.  

4.4.4 version device seems working